# how to store float[] in sql server in .net?

Tags: c#, database, arrays

I want to store float[] in sql server, what is the most efficient way to do this in c#?

Comment: It depends on what you will do with that array. One possible solution is to create N rows of `float`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since tables are sets of unordered rows and those rows can have attributes (columns) which can be of type `float`, the solution in a RDMS is to create a table with a column of type `float`. If you want those rows sequenced, you would need to add a column that would manage that.

Comment: what about storing the serialized array as blob?

Comment: @Benny - Not a recommend solution (especially with floats) if you want it to be maintainable. By far the best solution in an RDBMS is a table.

Comment: @Esteban Araya - I would need to know the nature of the values being stored. Still, on the whole, if this is data, I would recommend storing it in the structure specifically designed for that purpose which is a table.